# Why does armor in late-game nethack worse than the beginning armor?

Tags: nethack

[Viewing online](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Armor_class), I see that the nethack wiki says that a lower Armor Class is a better one. However, viewing the list comparing the armor [here](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Armor#Table_of_Armor_and_Properties), how could the beginning armor (like the Hawaiian t-shirt) provides better protection than something like crystal plate mail?

Well then, either I'm reading it wrong or the information isn't correct or clear.

Comment: The armor's AC is _subtracted_ from your character's AC.  Thus the shirts subtract 0 (no protection).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom So since the base AC is at 10, the Hawaiian Shirt doesn't reduce it at all, but the crystal plate mail puts it at 3 AC (assuming no other factors)?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Armor class is a very strange stat. A character with a lower AC stat takes less damage. However, your character's AC starts at 10 and the AC stat of each piece of armor you are wearing is **subtracted** from your character's AC stat. This means that it is better for your character to have a low AC stat, but it is better for armor to have a high AC stat.

As a side note, the t-shirt and Hawaiian t-shirt are actually quite valuable because they can be worn **under** armor. This means that they can be separately enchanted to +5 in an armor slot that nothing else can use.